# 0 , NULL, empty string, Default values - MySql Questions

Tags: mysql, database

1. Does **bool** value false == 0 and true == 1
2. Does **Null** value in varchar, int, date fields == 0?
3. When by default in mysql values == 0 or NULL or empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Question**: Does bool value false == 0 and true == 1

Yes - you can test using:

```
SELECT IF(0, 'true', 'false')
```

...it will return "false", meaning zero indicates false and one indicates true.  This example was taken from the [MySQL documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html).

> **Question**: Does Null value in varchar, int, date fields == 0?

No, NULL indicates the *lack* of any value at all.
You need to use special operators if you want to compare for the value being NULL.

> **Question**: When by default in mysql values == 0 or NULL or empty string?

Without default constraints in place, columns that allow NULL will contain NULL if no value has been provided -- regardless of data type (DATETIME, numeric, text, etc).  Columns that do not allow NULL will return an error until a value is provided that matches the data type of the column.  Default constraints allow you to specify a default value if someone attempts to insert a NULL value into the column, or the column has been omitted from an INSERT statement.

Comment: Any non-zero value is considered true, not just 1.

Answer (score 7):

Internally in MySQL there are no bool values. Expressions that appear to return booleans actually return an integer 0 or 1:

```
SELECT (3 < 5)
1

SELECT (3 > 5)
0

SELECT (3 < 4) + (4 < 5)
2

SELECT TRUE
1
```

TRUE and FALSE are just aliases for 1 and 0.

NULL does not equal any value, not even another NULL.

```
SELECT NULL = ''
NULL
SELECT NULL = NULL
NULL
```

If you want to compare with NULL use `IS NULL`.

---

Update: There was some confusion over whether MySQL supports booleans. This example shows that even a BOOL type on a column is still just an integer:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id INT, x BOOL);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1, TRUE),
(2, FALSE),
(3, 3);  -- Can you insert 3 into a BOOL type? Yep!
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
```

Results:

```
id   x
1    1
2    0
3    3
```

Comment: -1: Actually, there is bool/boolean in MySQL (though they're both synonyms for TINYINT): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: @OMG Ponies: From the page you posted: "However, the values TRUE and FALSE are merely aliases for 1 and 0, respectively."

Answer (score 1):

In SQL NULL represents the the absence of a value. In MySQL an explicit NULL may also represent the next value of a pseudo-sequence and an implicit NULL may represent an implicit default value (a zero or empty string) determined by MySQL.